# Display a value in one column based on a value in another column

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I have two columns:

1. ## Of Procs
2. ## Of Procs with a procedure time

If column 2 is blank, and column 1 has a value, then I need column 2 to display a zero. What would a formula look like for that?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your crosstab and explain which should get effected depending to other row?

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula

```
if ({Of Procs}="") then "0"
else {Of Procs}
```

I tested it and it works.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

if (isnull({TABLE.column 2}) or {TABLE.column 2}="")

```
and
```

(not(isnull({TABLE.column 1})) or  {TABLE.column 1}<>"")

then 
    "0"

else
   {TABLE.column 2}